# How do I create a "Clojure Application" project in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: clojure, enclojure

in Netbeans 6.8 / Enclojure 1.1.3 I have an option for "Clojure Application" when I create a new project. In Netbeans 6.9.1 / Enclojure 1.4(?) this option doesn't appear and instead there is the option of "Clojure Maven".

Am I missing something obvious? Is there an option for creating Clojure Application project in 6.9.1?

Answer (score 1):

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is the system for building the application from sources. Creating a "Clojure 1.2 Maven Project" creates a Clojure project that uses maven for the build process.